Force landscape mode when going full scren on mobile browsers
I'm currently writing a very simple game which renders into a canvas element, and I want to let people play it from their mobile browser (either Chrome or Firefox for Android, or iOS safari but I don't have an apple device to test it at the moment, so I'm ignoring it here). As I see it the user will be able to register, then on form submit the canvas will be put in full screen, and the device orientation will be forced in landscape.
So far I have encountered two methods, none of which work for both browsers :

The screen.<prefix>LockOrientation(mode) method, which has been deprecated and does not work (I have confirmed in the mozilla codebase that the implementation has been stripped to a stub).

The new ScreenOrientation api's screen.orientation.lock(mode), which works in chrome but does not in FFA. I have confirmed in their codebase that they did not implement the functionality as of today.


This should be the end of the story, I might file a missing feature report on bugzilla, except I know forcing screen orientation on FFA is possible, as I have seen some websites do it (YouTube when putting a video full screen, sovietscloset.com which uses an iframe from mediadelivery.net,...), only for video content however.
My question is thus : is there a third method to force screen orientation that I somehow haven't found yet, or do browsers simply behave differently when putting video content full screen as opposed to any normal tag ?
